# Where should I place 多 in large numbers?

Tags: grammar

Where should I put the "多“ in large numbers?
I saw in one text
300多万人
but
10亿多人

Comment: Sounds like you'll have an answer here: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/9414/3561

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are different in meaning:

300多万人:

(>300)万, maybe 301万 or 310 万...

10亿多人:

(>10亿), maybe 10亿+10000 or 10亿+1000000...